# Pandas - column median applied on lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

Given the dataset:

```
matrix = [(222, 34, 23),
         (333, 31, 11),
         (444, 16, 21),
         (555, 32, 22),
         (666, 33, 27),
         (777, 35, 11)
         ]
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))
```

I want to apply the formula `(value - column median) ^ 2`. I am trying to do with lambda and functions, but I am not being successful, the issue is the `column median`.

value = each cell;

how could I apply that function?

**Edit**

`dfObj['d'] = dfObj['c'].apply(lambda x : math.pow(x, 2) / 10)`

Comment: Your problem isn't with the lambda. It's that you're applying it to a non-existent column. Your DataFrame doesn't have a `"d"` column. I'm assuming you're getting a `KeyError`?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @PMende 'd' is a new column where the output will be saved. I wrote it wrong, I will edit.

Comment: @WeNYoBen for example, let's consider the column C. I would get the first item on row C (23) and divide it by the median of column (21.50), so it will be (23/21.50) ^2, and I will do it for each item on column c adding it respectively on column ´d´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
dfObj.div(dfObj.median())**2
Out[116]: 
          a         b         c
0  0.197531  1.094438  1.144402
1  0.444444  0.909822  0.261763
2  0.790123  0.242367  0.954029
3  1.234568  0.969467  1.047052
4  1.777778  1.031006  1.577069
5  2.419753  1.159763  0.261763
```

Comment: How could I apply it for only one column and not the whole dataset?

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeReis `dfObj.c.div(dfObj.c.median())**2`

Comment: Awesome that work, thank you so much. It is simpler than what I was trying to do.